# Getting Data from JSON with anystock

Tags: anychart

Based on [anychart doc](https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Data_From_JSON), it is very straight forward to load data :

```
var json = { "chart": { "type": "pie" }}
anychart.fromJson(json);
```

Now I am trying to do the same with anystock... but cannot figure out how:

```
var json = { "chart": { "type": "stock" }}
anychart.fromJson(json);
```

I have the error below :

> Unknown chart type: stock

I guess it is because `anychart` and `anystock` are 2 different products, but I cannot figure out what should be the correct configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an answer from anychart :

> unfortunately AnyStock 8.0.1 of October 2017 doesn't provide this
>   feature. However in future releases this feature might be implemented.